# .htaccess configuration for accessing different pages

Tags: .htaccess

I currently use the .htaccess file to "shortcut" the URL to a user's profile:

```
         RewriteEngine on
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gd/profile.php?username=$1
```

Now I want to do the same for "tags". When pressing a tag, go directly to a "tag page". For that I am adding the following to the code above:

RewriteEngine on

```
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gd/tags.php?tag_name=$1
```

The thing is that now the profile one doesn't work. How can I configure both so that neither one influences the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just catching “everything” with your pattern – so how do you expect the server to decide whether `/foo` should be a user profile or a tag …?

Unless you want to feed everything to *one* script and use your database to look up whether that refers to a user profile or a tag, I suggest you use urls of the form `/user/foo` and `/tag/foo` to distinguish between the two types – then you can easily catch the beginning `user/` resp. `tag/` in your RewriteRules for the two cases.

Apart from being easier to technically realize, this also gives your users the ability to see what content to expect from the URL path only, and you will also have no problems if you have a user profile *and* a tag named “foo” (which otherwise would lead to a problem).